# Jquery scroll animation not working on Laptop and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on `jquery` event where `div` with class `low_price` animates based on which direction we scroll.If we scroll up the div scrolls up and scrolls down when we scroll down.

But this code is not working on laptop mousepad scroll.

Even in IE it works very slow not as working on Chrome.

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/rx532h6o/) is a fiddle.

Here is the code.

```
 $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
         $(".low_price").animate({top: '0'}, "fast");
    }
    else {
         $(".low_price").animate({top: '80px'}, "fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't test this on track pad right now in order to investigate this, but one general thing I noticed is that you have to normalize the delta value between different browsers, as for example Firefox does not have `event.originalEvent.wheelDelta`. Something like this will do: `var delta = typeof e.wheelDelta != 'undefined' ? e.wheelDelta : (e.detail || e.deltaY)` (this will even support the jquery-mousewheel plugin)

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle example?

Comment: I have added a fiddle for the clarification of the question.